# Add user with root/administrative privileges

Tags: sudo, sshd

quick questions. I'm running lots of Debian boxes (as servers), we don’t install the UI.

We would like to setup monitoring Via a SSH connection (monitoring tool establishing an SSH connection to scan the box). We would like to create a dedicate user for this role (as opposed to using Root). I know I can install the `sudo` module, and give the new users root equivalent access (`ALL=(ALL) ALL`), but that requires the user to start each command with “sudo”, im not sure how that would work with the monitoring tool(s). Im from the Windows world. What would be the Linux equivalent to adding a user to the Administrators group in windows (giving the user full Administrative access)?

Please no lecture about safety practices

Oh one more question, can someone please point me to a good and "complete" SSH guide detailing ALL possible `sshd_config` options?

Thanks!

Comment: sudo is the best option. I use several tools (rundeck, nagios, Ansible, others), and they all play well with sudo

Comment: Thank you both for the info. Im looking into OpManager or SolarWinds, but im open for suggestions. Guess ill have to test, ill report back

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to adding a user to the Administrators group would be to add them to the `sudo` or `wheel` groups (depending on distribution). However, this will still require the user to run `sudo` in front of all commands, just as Windows still requires you to "Run as Administrator" when you want o use admin privileges. To add a new user with those privileges that doesn't need to use the `sudo` command, assign the new user a uid of 0. This is a bad idea, but it will do what I believe you want.

Answer (score -1):

Setting uid=0 gives user root privileges. It is basically the same as using `ALL=(ALL) ALL` (especially with `NOPASSWD`), but with `sudo` you will get at least some of the auditing though it can be altered by users with unlimited `sudo`).

Giving more precise information about your *monitoring tool* can be helpful to receive better answers.

> Oh one more question, can someone please point me to a good and "complete" SSH guide detailing ALL possible sshd_config options?

It is called manual page. You type [`man sshd_config`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5?query=sshd_config&sec=5) and all the options pop out.

Comment: Yes, I am not telling that it is a good idea, but a possible one. Even setting `ALL=(ALL) ALL` to normal users is security disaster.